# The Wikipedia definition of an Antisymmetric relation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

The Wikipedia definition of an Antisymmetric relation says :

> R is antisymmetric precisely if for all $a$ and  $b$ in $X$
>
> \begin{align}
> \text{if } R(a,b) \text{ and } R(b,a) \text{ then } a=b.
> \end{align}
>
> or, equivalently
>
> \begin{align}
> \text{if } R(a,b) \text{ with } a\ne b  \text{ then } R(b,a) \text{ must not hold. }
> \end{align}

**My Question :** Shouldn't the contrapositive of the first statement say

\begin{align}
\text{if } a\ne b \text{ then } R(a,b) \text{ or } R(b,a).
\end{align}

and in considering the mathematical sense of "or", it might as well happen that even if $R(a,b)$ holds ; nothing stops from $R(b,a)$ NOT being true.

Please help me resolve this.

Comment: No, the contrapositive is "if $a\ne b$ then $\lnot$ $\bigl(R(a,b)$ and $R(b,a)\bigr)$", or equivalently, "if $a\ne b$ then $\lnot R(a,b)$ or $\lnot R(b,a)$".

Comment: No. The contrapositive of "if $R(a,b)$ and $R(b,a)$, then $a=b$" is "if $a\ne b,$ then $R(a,b)$ and  $R(b,a)$ and not both true"; and "$R(a,b)$ and $R(b,a)$ are not both true" is equivalent to "if $R(a,b)$ is true, then $R(b,a)$ is false".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The contrapositive should be $$\text{if } a\ne b \text{ then it not true that } R(a,b) \text{ and } R(b,a)$$ and that is equivalent to $$\text{if } a\ne b \text{ then } R(a,b) \text{ does not hold or } R(b,a) \text{ does not hold }$$ which implies $$\text{if } R(a,b) \text{ with } a\ne b  \text{ then } R(b,a) \text{ must not hold. }$$

Comment: Rahul and bof both typed faster than me, but put similar answers as comments

Answer (score 6):

The notion of contrapositive can be generalized in the following way:

> **Theorem:** The following are logically equivalent:
>
> - If $A$ and $B$ then $C$
> - If $A$ and not $C$ then not $B$

This can be proven by using the following chain of equivalences

- $(A \wedge B) \implies C$
- $A \implies (B \implies C)$
- $A \implies (\neg C \implies \neg B)$
- $(A \wedge \neg C) \implies \neg B$

Answer (score 4):

No.

Let $R=\varnothing\subseteq X\times X$.

Then $R$ is antisymmetric but from $a\neq b$ it cannot be concluded that $\langle a,b\rangle\in R$ or $\langle b,a\rangle\in R$.

Answer (score 1):

Precisely because "$p$ or $q$" involves the possibility that both $p$ and $q$ be true, your proposal cannot work, since if both $aRb$ and $bRa$, then you would have $a=b$, absurd.

Besides that, remember that not every pair $(a,b)$ must be such that at least one of $aRb$ or $bRa$ holds: that might help you understand the quoted definition.

Answer (score 0):

If your proposed condition was equivalent to antisymmetry then all partial orders would be total orders. Thus any non-total partial order provides a counterexample. For example, on the set of positive integers let $R(a,b)$ denote the relation $a$ divides $b$. It is easy to see that $R$ is antisymmetric and indeed a partial order. Note that $2 \neq 3$, but neither $R(2,3)$ nor $R(3,2)$ hold.